# Installing rubygem d3js into a Rails 5 app, receiving railties compatibility issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, d3.js, rubygems

Has anyone successfully installed the D3js gem for rails. 
I have the recent version, gem 'd3js-rails', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.6'
When I bundle install I receive a message saying bundler cannot find compatible versions:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies.........
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    coffee-rails (~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
      railties (< 5.2.x, >= 4.0.0)

    d3js-rails (>= 3.1.6, ~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.1.6, which depends on
      railties (< 5.0, >= 3.0)

    rails (>= 5.0.0.1, ~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0.1, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0.1)

    react-rails (>= 1.7.1, ~> 1.7) was resolved to 1.9.0, which depends on
      railties (>= 3.2)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)
```

My gem file looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'

gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'devise'
gem 'd3js-rails', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'yahoo-finance'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem "better_errors"
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

What is the actual issue? Has anyone had similar problems with installing d3js-rails?

Answer (score 1):

Successfully installed found no issues.
Suggestion: Try to update your rubygem manager, rails & installed gems if they are not up to date. It seems you are having compatibility issues with your gems.
    gem update --system && gem update

Otherwise:
use

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.7.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.1'
gem 'react-rails', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.2'
```

instead of your current version then use

```
bundle update
```

and then

```
bundle install.
```

Hope this will work.
Good Luck!

Comment: I've updated my ruby gem manager using rubygems-update to latest version but am still getting the same compatibility issues.

Comment: see if all installed gems are up to date?

Comment: I've updated all my gems. But in my gemfile I'm using version numbers so I should be getting the specified versions. Still receiving the error.

Comment: can you share your gemfile

Comment: I'm not looking to remove rails 5. If I can't use d3 gem I'll probably just use it's cdn.

Comment: I have a Rails 4.2.6 app and successfully installed the gem so I need a work around for Rails 5

Comment: Sorry to say but it seems the only way to use d3. Its dependencies are still not compatible with rails 5 as d3 needs railties < 5.0